# Get mx record of email address with php then redirect

Tags: php, html

I need a little assistance to complete my code. I want to check for the mx record of an email address from a form on my website and if the email address is hosted by google apps then I want the page to redirect to a different page than where other emails redirect to.

I know I can check for the mx record either using `dns_get_record`, `checkdnsrr` or `getmxrr()`  but I don't know how to complete the code.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];<br>
$domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);<br>
$mx = dns_get_record('$domain', DNS_MX, );
```

This is where I get stuck. How would I implement this in php: if `$mx` includes `aspmx.l.google.com` redirect to `www.example.com`

This is not a duplicate question. I am trying to use php to redirect to a new page based on the mx record of the email address. The mx record query should locate `aspmx.l.google.com` and then redirect based on that but if mx record doesnt contain `aspmx.l.google.com` it should redirect to a different page.

Comment: If you would to redirect, you could do **header('Location: *https : //www.google.com*');** However, it must be at the head of your document (or the end of your first group of PHP code at the head of your document). If you don't know what I mean, a simple Google search may help you out.

Comment: @TyQ. I know how to redirect in php. But what i need this script to do is check mx, if mx is google apps then redirect to a certain page but if mx is not google apps it should redirect to a different page.

Comment: Oh, well, I can't really help you out there. Sorry. :-/

Comment: what does $mx return currently?

Comment: @Machavity this is not a duplicate. Pls read through before jumping into conclusions. Thanks

Comment: @nogad It returns an array and thats where i get confused on how to go about writing the remaining part of the code.

`3 => 
  array (
    'host' => 'google.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => 600,
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => 50,
    'target' => 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'host' => 'google.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => 600,
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => 20,
    'target' => 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com',
  ),
)`

Comment: show me the array and i can give you the rest of code

Comment: http://ideone.com/lQgokO you may want to skip the loop and use the first array if that is going to be reliable

Comment: @nogad Ok i will test that now. This is how the array looks [link](http://imgur.com/a/PqsdA)

Comment: @nogad hi bro tested but it didnt work [link](http://ideone.com/Ii0p4a)

Comment: whats the value of $email?

Comment: @BrianSmith It is a duplicate. The duplicate tells you how to get a list of the MX records. Then you can do your comparison

Comment: @nogad hi bro, the value of $email is an email address. The email address is posted from the form to the .php file